# Evaluate whether a function $f$ is 1. continuous at 0; 2. differentiable at 0.

Tags: continuity

Evaluate whether a function $f$ is:
1. continuous at 0; 
2. differentiable at 0

a)
$$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & \quad x \space rational \\
            1+x & \quad x \space irrational
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
b)
$$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & \quad x \space rational \\
            x(1+x) & \quad x \space irrational 
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
c)
$$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & \quad x \space rational \\
            x^2(1+x) & \quad x \space irrational
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Apparently, one can use differentiation rules to solve this problem.
But I have got no clue what x rational and x irrational means

Thanks in advance

Comment: $x$ rational means it can be written as $a/b$, where $a,b$ are integers. So for example, $3/5$ is rational. $x$ irrational means it is a real number but cannot be written in this form. $\pi, \sqrt{2}$ are examples of irrational numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number is called rational iff it is the fraction $p/q$ of some integers $p,q$ with $q \neq 0$; otherwise it is called irrational. For instance, the number $4$ is rational; for we have $4 = 8/2$. But the number $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational (can you prove this?).

I will do (a) and (b) for your reference; you may thus try to do (c) yourself, for the reason that the questions look like exercises.

For (a) observe that $|f(x) - f(0)| > 1$ for all irrational $x > 0$; hence $f$ is not continuous from the right at $0$, implying that $f$ is not continuous at $0$. Hence $f$ is not differentiable at $0$ (why?).

For (b) observe that, if $x \in \Bbb{R}$, then $|f(x) - f(0)| \leq |x||1+x|$; if in addition $|x| < 1$, then $|x+1| \leq |x|+1 < 2$, implying $|x||1+x| < 2|x|$; given any $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $2|x| < \varepsilon$ if in addition $|x| < \varepsilon/2$. Hence, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, if $|x| < \min \{1, \varepsilon/2 \}$ then $|f(x) - f(0)| < \varepsilon$; this shows that $f$ is continuous at $0$.
To investigate differentiability of $f$ at $0$, note that, if $x > 0$ is irrational, then
$$
\frac{|f(x) - f(0)|}{|x|} = |1+x| > 1;
$$
hence $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Aha, thanks for the answer, now it makes sense :D